# (caadr exp) in assignment-variable

Tags: scheme, racket, sicp

I am reading [4.1.2 Representing Expressions](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-26.html#%_sec_4.1.2) of SICP,

which defines `definition-variable`.

```
  (define (definition? exp)
    (tagged-list? exp 'define))

  (define (definition-variable exp)
    (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
        (cadr exp)
        (caadr exp))) ;;
```

Refer to the conditionals

```
    (if (symbol? (cadr exp))
        (cadr exp)
        (caadr exp))) ;;
```

I am not very sure what `(caadr exp)` returned? is it a null or `'()`

The variable case

```
(define ⟨var⟩ ⟨value⟩)
```

`(cadr exp)` returns the second element as variable,

but alternative to procedure case:

```
  (define (⟨var⟩ ⟨param₁⟩ … ⟨paramₙ⟩)
    ⟨body⟩)
```

the expression (caadr exp))) is `(car (car (cdr x)))`

Since cadr is var, then caadr is a null?

Comment: Note that `null` is simply a name for the empty list, so `null` and `'()` are the same thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the procedure case, `(cadr exp)` is not the name but a list whose first element is the name.

```
         (cadr exp)
             |
             v
         +-------+
         |       |
 (define (f a b c) body)  <--- exp
          ^
          |
      (caadr exp)
```

If you evaluate it:

```
(caadr '(define (⟨var⟩ ⟨param₁⟩ … ⟨paramₙ⟩) ⟨body⟩))
-->
(caar '((⟨var⟩ ⟨param₁⟩ … ⟨paramₙ⟩) ⟨body⟩))
-->
(car '(⟨var⟩ ⟨param₁⟩ … ⟨paramₙ⟩))
-->
⟨var⟩
```

Comment: ty, when reading the answer, I suddenly comfortable with parentheses just as a switch in the brain are burst open.